# Rspec expect to recieve message with attributes and ignore others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, test-double

I'm trying to write a spec for a really long time.

I need to test this:

```
expect(Foo).to receive(:bar).with(some_args)
```

and everything works just fine if `Foo` receives `bar` only once. But it will receive `bar` several times for sure so that the string above fails with

```
#<Foo (class)> received :bar with unexpected arguments
```

on those calls.

How can I test that `Foo` receives `bar` with the exact arguments I need and ignore other cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `allow(Foo).to receive(:bar).and_call_original`?

For example, these tests will successfully pass:

```
class Foo
  def boo(b)
    b
  end
end

describe Foo do
  let(:a) { Foo.new }

  before do
    allow(a).to receive(:boo).and_call_original
  end

  it do
    expect(a).to receive(:boo).with(2)

    expect(a.boo(1)).to eq 1
    expect(a.boo(2)).to eq 2
    expect(a.boo(3)).to eq 3
  end
end
```

If you add `expect(a).to receive(:boo).with(4)` to the block, the test will fail. It seems like what you're looking for, right?

Comment: That's it. I thought I tried it and that didn't work out. But I tried once again now and it all done, thanx! (I must have forgotten to save changes when tried it on my own, cause I had exact this line commented out:) )

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work anymore, and I haven't found anything more recent about it.  How can I find information about the limitations or changes to this?

Comment: @ShadSterling which version of rspec do you use? I guess it should still work

Comment: @Ngoral Gemfile.lock has spec-core (3.11.0).  I was adapting the spec for an old class to test its replacement and the error I thought was this was fixed as a side effect of fixing other failing tests, so unfortunately I'm not sure what the actual problem was